# Access array from another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please, if is it possible to define array in one function and access this, from another function in javascript?

Comment: Yes it is. It's also a very, very basic task so you might want to take a step back and read a good JS book or tutorial.

Comment: Make it global and you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: Yes, the question is very simple, but why to downvote it? I haven't enough reputation to make vote.

Comment: Please take back your downvote.

Comment: Yes/no questions are not very suitable for SO. You should rather post your code and ask a specific question about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
function a() { x = ['a','b']; };
a();
function b() { alert(x[0]); }
b(); //alerts 'a'
```

Comment: You should declare `x` in the global scope. That code alone would throw an error in strict mode.

Comment: I mean sure, in an ideal world, but then I wouldn't be defining the array in one function and accessing it in another, which is what the question asked for.

Comment: I said declare, not define. You're already implicitly declaring it globally, which is an error in strict mode unless you do it explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

I think better should be:

```
var x =[]; 

function a() {  x = ['a','b']; };
a();

function b() { alert(x[0]); }
b(); //alerts 'a'
```

Using **var** to declare the variable at the scope needed

Comment: Barring the first line, this is a straight up copy of dave's answer (neither has been edited yet). It would have been better to suggest an edit with that line in to his answer than duplicate, which adds noise.

Comment: var x =[];  I must declare in script tag in HEAD section or elsewhere in a body?

Comment: @user332689 let's assume you can group your functions inside the same script file you should declare the var at the begging of that file.